# JVM and Von neumann architecture

Tags: java, architecture, jvm, von-neumann

I read somewhere that Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is not Von-neumann architecture.
Can someone please clarify why and/or how?

Comment: Your source says *nothing* about it? Java provides you with parallel computing so maybe that's why you could say it's not a von Neuman language.

Comment: no it is actually just a line in one of the PPTs..... i tried to google for answer but it seems my googling skills arent good

Comment: Where did you read that? My first thought is that it's not von neumann because it may or may not be depending on JVM implementation or host environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM can be considered to be Harvard architecture rather than Von Neumann architecture, on the grounds that it *separates code from data*; they are treated as distinct kinds of things which are accessed via separate means.

However, this is not a particularly useful statement, because in an object-oriented VM like the JVM there is not a single untyped address space, or two of them, but rather *many* distinct kinds (classes) which cannot be addressed uniformly (outside of reflection operations, which are more or less bypassing the rules of the VM).